# Speeding up a MySQL query, tried both normal and a join - same speed

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm using a MyISAM database with about 22 million rows of data in it, I need to run a query on it, but it's too slow and is halting my incoming traffic, which I'd like to avoid.

I have tested the query on our dev server, which has about 2.2 million rows and it takes about 3.7 seconds average for both of these queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gg.token
FROM analytics aa
JOIN game_sessions gg
ON aa.session_token = gg.token
AND aa.timestamp > '2013-10-20 00:00:00'
and aa.action = "validate"
and gg.solved = 1
```

With this EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  aa  ALL session_token   NULL    NULL    NULL    12317871    Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  gg  ref token   token   23  fc.aa.session_token 1   Using where
```

and I also tried the following which gives the same result:

```
select DISTINCT gg.token
from analytics aa, game_sessions gg
where aa.session_token = gg.token
and aa.action = "validate"
and gg.solved = 1
and gg.timestamp >= STR_TO_DATE('10/20/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

With this EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  aa  ALL session_token   NULL    NULL    NULL    12317913    Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  gg  ref token   token   23  fc.aa.session_token 1   Using where
```

They both take about 3.7 seconds, Ideally I could make this much, much faster so I can use it on my production database. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Indexes: 'token' on game_sessions and same with 'session_token' on analytics.

EDIT: gg.solved is int(11), gg.action is VARCHAR(100), gg.timestamp is TIMESTAMP

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN on the query?

Comment: And shouldn't you be looking at doing a LEFT JOIN rather than the default OUTER JOIN?

Comment: So you've not indexed `aa.timestamp`, `aa.action` or `gg.solved`? (What specific field types are these?)

Comment: Just added explains to the question!

Comment: They are not indexed, no. This is not a common lookup.

Comment: solved is int(11), action is VARCHAR(100), solved is INT(11)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps?

```
SELECT DISTINCT gg.token
  FROM game_sessions gg
  LEFT JOIN analytics aa
    ON aa.session_token = gg.token
   WHERE aa.timestamp > '2013-10-20 00:00:00'
   AND aa.action = "validate"
 AND gg.solved = 1
```

Comment: Still the same 3.7 seconds here. Maybe this is as good as it gets?

Comment: Pretty much same query so...well without index and that many rows it's hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, try:

```
create index idx1 on analytics (timestamp,validate);
create index idx2 on game_sessions (token, solved);
```

Note that the field "solved" alone probably makes up a crappy index since it seems as a boolean value.

regards,